# Why does my GUI for Minecraft not clear the sword and set the bow when it is set to do so?

Tags: java, bukkit

I am a plugin developer for a server on Minecraft, and I am running into a problem with removing the diamond sword in the GUI and placing the bow in the GUI when I click on the "Accept." What I need it to eventually do is take that diamond sword, clear it when the trade-up has been accepted, then add the bow into the corresponding slot for the player to then take.

```
private Inventory i = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, ChatColor.BOLD + "Trade-Up"); //Creating an inventory for everything to work around

public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}//Registering the event

private void openGUI(Player player) {
    player.closeInventory();

    ItemStack Anvil = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 3);
    ItemMeta AnvilMeta = Anvil.getItemMeta();

    AnvilMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Trade Up");
    Anvil.setItemMeta(AnvilMeta);

    ItemStack AnvilAccept = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 5);
    ItemMeta AnvilAcceptMeta = AnvilAccept.getItemMeta();

    AnvilAcceptMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Accept");
    AnvilAccept.setItemMeta(AnvilAcceptMeta);

    ItemStack AnvilFirst = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 7);
    ItemMeta AnvilFirstMeta = AnvilFirst.getItemMeta();

    AnvilFirstMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + "Input Items Here");
    AnvilFirst.setItemMeta(AnvilFirstMeta);

    ItemStack AnvilSecond = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 7);
    ItemMeta AnvilSecondMeta = AnvilSecond.getItemMeta();

    AnvilSecondMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + "Output Items Here");
    AnvilSecond.setItemMeta(AnvilSecondMeta);

    i.setItem(0, Anvil);
    i.setItem(1, Anvil);
    i.setItem(3, AnvilFirst);
    i.setItem(4, AnvilAccept);
    i.setItem(5, AnvilSecond);
    i.setItem(7, Anvil);
    i.setItem(8, Anvil);

    player.openInventory(i);
}//Opens the trade-up inventory when the player type the command

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("trade-up")) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            openGUI(player);
        }//GUI openning command
    }
    return false;
}

@EventHandler
public void inventoryClickEvent(InventoryClickEvent e) {

    ItemStack Anvil = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 3);
    ItemMeta AnvilMeta = Anvil.getItemMeta();

    AnvilMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Trade Up");
    Anvil.setItemMeta(AnvilMeta);

    ItemStack AnvilAccept = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 5);
    ItemMeta AnvilAcceptMeta = AnvilAccept.getItemMeta();

    AnvilAcceptMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Accept");
    AnvilAccept.setItemMeta(AnvilAcceptMeta);

    ItemStack AnvilFirst = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 7);
    ItemMeta AnvilFirstMeta = AnvilFirst.getItemMeta();

    AnvilFirstMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + "Input Items Here");
    AnvilFirst.setItemMeta(AnvilFirstMeta);

    ItemStack AnvilSecond = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 7);
    ItemMeta AnvilSecondMeta = AnvilSecond.getItemMeta();

    AnvilSecondMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + "Output Items Here");
    AnvilSecond.setItemMeta(AnvilSecondMeta);

    ItemStack is = e.getCurrentItem();

    if(is.equals(Anvil) || is.equals(AnvilFirst) || is.equals(AnvilSecond)) {
        e.setCancelled(true);//Making sure that the player doesn't take the glass panes
    }

    if(is.equals(AnvilAccept)) {
        Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();

        ItemStack air = new ItemStack(Material.AIR);

        ItemStack chests = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
        ItemStack chestsConvert = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);

        if(i.contains(chests, 2)) {
            i.setItem(6, chestsConvert);
            i.clear(2);
            i.setItem(0, Anvil);
            i.setItem(1, Anvil);
            i.setItem(3, AnvilFirst);
            i.setItem(4, AnvilAccept);
            i.setItem(5, AnvilSecond);
            i.setItem(7, Anvil);
            i.setItem(8, Anvil);
            p.closeInventory();
            p.openInventory(i);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your items have been Traded-Up!");//Removes the sword and gives them a bow instead
        }else if(i.contains(air, 2)) {
            p.sendMessage("There is no items to trade up!");
        } //Makes sure there is an item to trade-up

    e.setCancelled(true);//Makes so the player can't take the "Accept" pane.
    }
}
```

The plugin doesn't register that anything is in the slot nor does it remove and replace the diamond sword with the bow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains(ItemStack, int)` method doesn't check whether that kind of `ItemStack` is at slot `int` (the way I see you using it) but checks whether the entire contents of that inventory contain at least that integer amount of the `ItemStack`. Your code is checking whether the custom inventory contains two diamond swords (which can be done if you place them in slot two and six), instead of checking whether a single diamond sword has been placed in slot two (which is what I am assuming you are trying to do).

To fix this, use `inventory.getItem(2).equals(chests)` to check whether slot two contains the sword. Note that the method above won't return an `ItemStack` of type `Material.AIR` in the case of an empty slot but will instead return `null`.

Here is some example code of how this could look:

```
ItemStack input = i.getItem(2); // Get the ItemStack at slot two

if (input == null) { // If there is nothing in that slot
    player.sendMessage("There are no items to trade up!");
} else if (input.equals(chests)) { // If it contains the sword
    // Execute the trade
}
// Optionally send message if it is the wrong item
```

The way you're defining and initializing the custom `Inventory` and `ItemStack`s could be reversed. Note that multiple people can view and interact with the same inventory, so the way you have your plugin written right now, everyone using the "trade-up" interface will see the same inventory and will be able to take other people's items. The `ItemStack`s however that you are newly creating for every event and `openGUI(Player)` method call are not unique and could, in place of the inventory, only be created once to save resources (in other words, you could create a new `Inventory` every time the `openGUI(Player)` method is called, but always reference the same `ItemStack`s).